# C++ second cin got eaten when the Input type isn't correct

Tags: c++, cin

I would like to ask a strange question.

```cpp
double Test1, Test2;

cout << "Please Input the First Number: ";
cin >> Test1;

cout << "\nPlease Input the Second Number: ";
cin >> Test2;

cout << "\nHere is the Answer: " << endl;
cout << Test1 << Test2 << endl;
```

If my Input of `Test1` is a char (for example 'A'), the second input will be eaten.

I've tried to use `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max())` and `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')` but nothing seems to work.

Why is this problem happening?

Comment: NO. If your first input is `'A'` -- a *matching failure* occurs, character extraction from the input stream ceases leaving `'A'` unread which causes the same failure to occurs with `Test2`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks, I am just curious why this is happening.

Comment: Technically, when the *matching failure* occurs `failbit` is set on the input stream which causes the second input to fail because it has not been cleared. See [std::ios_base::iostate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) and see - with example - [std::basic_ios::clear](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Okay, I would like to know is there any way to clear the input stream so that the second input can be use as normal?

Comment: Yes. [std::basic_istream::ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) (with example)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am really appreciated for your kind help, Thank you.

Comment: Bookmark [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/) it is the best reference on the net. Good luck with your coding!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Oops, It seems like both `cin.clear();` and `cin.ignore();` doesn't work normally. ;(

Comment: `std::cin.clear(); std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` Include `<limits>`.

Comment: [Full Example With Both Inputs](https://paste.opensuse.org/66198598) -- There is more than one way to structure the logic, but those are the complete validations to use every time.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I found out that I've been using either one of the function but not both. The problem have sloved now. Thankyou very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input with `>>` is terminated as soon as an invalid character is detected.  That invalid character is not removed from the stream, so it's still there when you do the second `>>`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there any way to remove the invalid character from the stream?

Comment: look up fflush(stdin)

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 I think thats something of C but not C++?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 `fflush(stdin)` in *Undefined Behavior* specified in the C standard unless `stdin` is a *seekable stream*. Only Microsoft provides a Non-Standard implementation of `fflush(stdin)` that allows flushing all input streams -- Do Not Use It!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Oh! Okay. I didn't know that. I think its time I switched from MVCC to gcc/clang.

Comment: All three compilers are good, but like most things MS, you have to understand the non-standard implementations. Now gcc/clang have far superior C compilers, but for C++ `cl.exe` isn't a bad compiler (but neither are gcc/clang `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I concur. (Does not belong here, but I was more surprised when I learnt that `std::string` class in MS has an `_Equal` function, to get around `\0` problems)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `char` type can not be converted to `double` by default.

Instead what you could do is declare both `Test1` and `Test2` as `std::string` type.

And if you want to convert them to `double` type, for example you are going to do some math calculation with them, you could do:

```
double d1 = std::stod(Test1);
```

Also you would need to `#include <string>` to use `std::string`.

---

#### Edit:

About why you never get to input the second time, when you enter `'A'` for `cin >> Test1`, a fail flag was put onto you input stream. Because of that, all `cin` afterwards would not work unless the flag was resolved.

If you want to make it works again, you could add:

```
if(std::cin.fail())
{
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

after the first `cin`.

The `cin.ignore()` approach you tried was correct. However, you didn't reset the flag with `cin.clear()`.

Comment: No, I don't need those char working. I'm just curious why clearing cin buffer won't fix the "second cin eating problem".

Comment: @KutengF I have re-edited my post, this should solve your problem.